# Is there a way to visualize what "Minimal sufficiency" and "Completeness" of a statistic means?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

As defined (for example, in Wikipedia):

**Completeness** is a property of a statistic in relation to a model for a set of observed data. In essence, it is a condition which ensures that the parameters of the probability distribution representing the model can all be estimated on the basis of the statistic: it ensures that the distributions corresponding to different values of the parameters are distinct.

**A sufficient statistic** is minimal sufficient if it can be represented as a function of any other sufficient statistic. Intuitively, a minimal sufficient statistic most efficiently captures all possible information about the parameter θ.

What I am looking for is a way to visualize either of these two explanations (intuitions?) in some way.

Any suggestions on how that might be done?